# Problem inserting into a std::map with C++

Tags: c++

I've got a compiler warning over a map insert, I've used std:map many times before and I must be having a block of some kind because I just can't see whats wrong.  I've created the following types in an effort to see where the issue is:

```
typedef std::string staledatamapkey_t;
typedef staledata_t staledatamapvalue_t;
typedef std::map<staledatamapkey_t, staledatamapvalue_t> staledatamap_t;
typedef std::pair<staledatamapkey_t, staledatamapvalue_t> statedatapair_t;
```

In a class I define the map as a member:

```
staledatamap_t m_staledata;
```

The code to insert into the map:

```
   for (unsigned i = 0; i < xAllstaledata.size (); ++i)
    {
        staledataXML_t const &xStaledata = xAllstaledata[i];
        staledatamapvalue_t staledata;
        staledatamapkey_t udn;
        statedatapair_t staledatapair;
        udn = staledata.udn = xStaledata.udn();
        staledata.expiry    = xStaledata.expiry();
        staledata.ddo       = xStaledata.ddo();
        staledata.tolerance = xStaledata.tolerance();
        staledata.ip        = xStaledata.ip();
        staledatapair = std::make_pair(udn, staledata);
        m_staledata.insert(staledatapair);
    }
```

The start of the compiler errors, which is referring to the `insert` line above:

```
config.C: In member function ‘void namespace::config_t::initialize(const string&)’:
config.C:199:54: error: use of deleted function ‘std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, namespace::config_t::staledata_t>& std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, namespace::config_t::staledata_t>::operator=(const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, namespace::config_t::staledata_t>&)’
         staledatapair = std::make_pair(udn, staledata);
                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/string:40,
                 from /home/u243348@PORT.L-3Com.com/work-somedir/install/include/CCcommon/version.H:19,
                 from config.H:13,
                 from config.C:11:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:208:12: note: ‘std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, namespace::config_t::staledata_t>& std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, namespace::config_t::staledata_t>::operator=(const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, namespace::config_t::staledata_t>&)’ is implicitly declared as deleted because ‘std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, namespace::config_t::staledata_t>’ declares a move constructor or move assignment operator
     struct pair
            ^~~~
config.C:200:41: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, namespace::config_t::staledata_t>::insert(namespace::config_t::statedatapair_t&)’
         m_staledata.insert(staledatapair);
                                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/map:61,
                 from config.H:15,
                 from config.C:11:
```

Can anyone see what I don't ?

[Edit] Modified typedefs:

```
    typedef std::string staledatamapkey_t;
    typedef staledata_t staledatamapvalue_t;
    typedef std::map<const staledatamapkey_t, staledatamapvalue_t> staledatamap_t;
    typedef std::pair<const staledatamapkey_t, staledatamapvalue_t> statedatapair_t;
```

I've also swapped the `insert` for `emplace`.

Still getting errors:

```
config.C:199:42:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/8/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, namespace::config_t::staledata_t>::pair(std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, const namespace::config_t::staledata_t>&)’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/string:40,
                 from /home/u243348@PORT.L-3Com.com/work-somedir/install/include/CCcommon/version.H:19,
                 from config.H:13,
                 from config.C:11:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:436:9: note: candidate: ‘template<class ... _Args1, long unsigned int ..._Indexes1, class ... _Args2, long unsigned int ..._Indexes2> std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::tuple<_Args1 ...>&, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes1 ...>, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes2 ...>)’
         pair(tuple<_Args1...>&, tuple<_Args2...>&,
         ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:436:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/string:41,
                 from /home/u243348@PORT.L-3Com.com/work-somedir/install/include/CCcommon/version.H:19,
                 from config.H:13,
                 from config.C:11:
/usr/include/c++/8/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4: note:   ‘std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, const namespace::config_t::staledata_t>’ is not derived from ‘std::tuple<_Tps ...>’
```

[Edit2] staledata_t:

```
struct staledata_t
    {
        std::string udn;                    //< Unique Data Number
        std::string expiry;                 //< Watchdog expiry
        std::string ddo;                    //< Different Data Only Flag
        std::string tolerance;              //< Data change tolerance
        std::string ip;                     //< Indicator placement

        QImage img;                         //< Stale image/icon
        QTimer watchdog;                    //< Watchdog timer
        bool stale;                         //< true if data stale else false

        staledata_t()
        {
            QObject::connect(&watchdog, &QTimer::timeout, [this] {
                if ( stale != false ) {
    //Already stale, do nothing
                    return;
                }
                stale = true;
            });
            stale = false;            
        }
        void kickWatchdog()
        {
            const QString timeStr(expiry.data());
            const QTime tm(QTime::fromString(timeStr));
            const int msecs(tm.msec());
            watchdog.start(msecs);
        }
    };
```

Comment: The `element_type` for a map is not `std::pair<Key, Value>`, but `std::pair<const Key, Value>`. Personally I'd just use `emplace` and avoid the explicit usage of `pair` completely, though: `m_staledata.emplace(udn, staledata)`.

Comment: Thank you, I will take another look and modify the pair typedef as you suggest.

Comment: You can also do `typedef typename staledatamap_t::value_type statedatapair_t;`; but again, any explicit usage of that `std::pair` IMO is just making the code heavier.

Comment: Is `staledata_t` copy assignable?

Comment: `insert` also requires copyable values, while `emplace` just needs moveable.

Comment: @ChrisMM, staledata_t is actually a struct.

Comment: @Quimby, have swapped insert for emplace, still getting errors

Comment: Being a struct doesn't mean it has to be copyable. When calling make_pair, it's complaining it can't copy assign, which indicates that your struct probably isn't copyable.

Comment: @SPlatten *staledata_t is actually a struct.* -- That is probably the most important pieces of information you are leaving out.  Let's see the struct.

Comment: The `struct` is not copyable as it contains a `QTimer`; given that this is a "live" object, I'd allocate it on the heap and put it in the map through a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @SPlatten Can you post how you are using `emplace`? You need to do the ugly piecewise tag construct, or use the much nicer `try_emplace` C++17 version.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I rewrote, replacing the use of struct with a class and also crossing over to `QMap` instead of `std::map`:

```
    class staledata_t : QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    private:
        QString m_ddo;                    //< Different Data Only Flag
        QString m_expiry;                 //< Watchdog expiry
        QString m_ip;                     //< Indicator placement
        QString m_tolerance;              //< Data change tolerance
        QString m_udn;                    //< Unique Data Number
        QImage m_img;                     //< Stale image/icon
        QTimer m_watchdog;                //< Watchdog timer
        bool m_stale;                     //< true if data stale else false

    public:
        staledata_t() : QObject(nullptr)
        {
            QObject::connect(&m_watchdog, &QTimer::timeout, [this] {
                if ( m_stale != false ) {
    //Already stale, do nothing
                    return;
                }
                m_stale = true;
            });
            m_stale = false;
        }
        void kickWatchdog()
        {
            const QTime tm(QTime::fromString(m_expiry));
            const int msecs(tm.msec());
            m_watchdog.start(msecs);
            m_stale = false;
        }
        const QString& ddo() { return m_ddo; }
        const QString& expiry() { return m_expiry; }
        const QImage& img() { return m_img; }
        const QString& ip() { return m_ip; }
        void setDDO(const QString &ddo) { m_ddo = ddo; }
        void setExpiry(const QString &expiry) { m_expiry = expiry; }
        void setIMG(const QImage& img) { m_img = img; }
        void setIP(const QString& ip) { m_ip = ip; }
        void setStale(bool stale) { m_stale = stale; }
        void setTolerance(const QString& tolerance) { m_tolerance = tolerance; }
        void setUDN(const QString &udn) { m_udn = udn; }
        bool stale() { return m_stale; }
        const QString udn() { return m_udn; }

        Q_PROPERTY(QString ddo READ ddo WRITE setDDO)
        Q_PROPERTY(QString expiry READ expiry WRITE setExpiry)
        Q_PROPERTY(QImage img READ img WRITE setIMG)
        Q_PROPERTY(QString ip READ ip WRITE setIP)
        Q_PROPERTY(bool stale READ stale WRITE setStale)
        Q_PROPERTY(QString tolerance READ tolerance WRITE setTolerance)
        Q_PROPERTY(QString udn READ udn WRITE setUDN)
    };
```

Types:

```
    typedef QString staledatamapkey_t;
    typedef staledata_t* staledatamapvalue_t;
    typedef QMap<const staledatamapkey_t, staledatamapvalue_t> staledatamap_t;
```

Usage:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < xAllstaledata.size (); ++i)
    {
        const staledataXML_t xStaledata = xAllstaledata[i];
        staledatamapvalue_t staledata = new staledata_t;
        staledatamapkey_t udn(xStaledata.udn);
        staledata->setUDN(udn);
        staledata->setExpiry(xStaledata.expiry);
        staledata->setDDO(xStaledata.ddo);
        staledata->setTolerance(xStaledata.tolerance);
        staledata->setIP(xStaledata.ip);
        m_staledata.insert(udn, staledata);
    }
```

Comment: *replacing the use of struct with a class* -- There is no difference in C++ between a `struct` and a `class` except for the default access specifier (`public` for struct, `private` for a class).  Thus that change made no difference.  Then `QString` and `std::string` are perfectly copyable items, thus that made no difference.

Comment: I was also missing `setTolerance` method.

Comment: If indeed you are unable to delete and/or unaccept it, you might consider the other option which I pointed out. It will otherwise be hard to prevent users from making your content directly visible (you probably noticed that it already happened) or from your content to be indirectly visible anyway. If you already did (though my gut feeling says you did not), you can verify that the result is matching your needs.